# Excel Formula, Get Last Row where Range is dynamic

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get the last row number of a range, But the range will be dynamic.

I can't use a named range , as sometimes the range defined can change on my spreadsheet. Ie one day the named range may be 50 rows, the next may be 51. To my knowledge the name range won't modify itself.

I need something like, Get the last row where A:A = 'stack'.

Trying to do something like, https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html , having trouble implementing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post any code you have had trouble implementing, and let us know what errors you get at what line, or if no errors, what the expected output is compared to the actual output.  Are you basically trying to find the last row, in a column, where some string appears?

Comment: Please post a data sample and explain in context. Is there any text in the column after `stack`?

Comment: What does `A:A='stack'` mean?  `A:A` refers to the entire column `A`, so the statement does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a column with text, you can find the last row that has a specific value with this formula. It is an array formula and has to be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=MAX((A1:A100="stack")*(ROW(A1:A100)))
```

See cell C1 in the screenshot below.

You can work this function into a dynamic range name. This formula always starts the range in A1 and goes down to the last occurrence of a cell that has the text "stack":

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,MAX((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100="stack")*(ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100))),1)
```

In the Name Manager, you don't need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter, since all named formulas are automatically evaluated as array formulas. If you use this approach, it would be best to limit the number of rows in the formula and not use whole column references.

Note the marching ants in the screenshot that circle the current range.

[image]

If you want to include all rows up to the last row with text, then you can use a simpler formula.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,MATCH("zzzzz",Sheet1!$A:$A,1),1)
```

With Match, you can use a whole column reference.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your first cell never changes, and let's say it's `"A1"`. For this you should use a snippet like this:

```
private function get_last_row(byref ws as worksheet, optional byval letter_of_first_col as string = "A", optional byval index_of_first_row as interger = 1) as long
    with ws
        get_last_row = .range(letter_of_first_row & index_of_first_row).currentRegion.rows.count + (index_of_first_row - 1)
    end with
end function
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, how do I use this, I put it into my vba editor and then go to my sheet and try to do `=get_last_row(A1)` but the function doesnt even come up after i do `=`